# how to open a file on android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and programming. I am using the android touchpaint api, and using the following code to save a drawing, but obviously saving is useless without being able to open the file.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with some code for it.

```
    // Function saves image to file
public String save(Bitmap mBitmap, boolean showMsg) {
    String filename;
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    filename = sdf.format(date);
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/modTouchPaint/";
        File file1 = new File(path);
        file1.mkdirs();

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, filename + ".jpg");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        if (showMsg)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture saved to " + path + filename + ".jpg", 9000).show();

        return path + filename + ".jpg";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please make sure that SD card is installed", 5000).show();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.